# How to append string before every third line in file

Tags: unix, sed, awk

File is

```
a@gmail.com,b@yahoo.com
xyz@gmail.com
abc@gmail.com 
ff@yahoo.co.in
jf@rediff.com
oop@hotmail.com
```

Output should be:

```
U|a@gmail.com,b@yahoo.com
D|xyz@gmail.com
R|abc@gmail.com 
U|ff@yahoo.co.in
D|jf@rediff.com
R|oop@hotmail.com
```

I want to append specific string after every 3rd character.

Comment: Confusing question. `string before every third line`? or `string after every 3rd character`? or `string before every line`? Lady, please make up your mind.

Comment: String before every third Line. [ not before/after character]

Comment: I want to append U before every 3rd line then same with D and R , but the thing is character which I want to append is different. I want to append specific characters before every line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
s/^/U|/
n
s/^/D|/
n
s/^/R|/
```

[Useful one-line scripts for sed](http://catonmat.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/09/sed1line.txt)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {split("UDR",p,"")} {print p[((NR-1)%3)+1] "|" $0}' a.txt
U|a@gmail.com,b@yahoo.com
D|xyz@gmail.com
R|abc@gmail.com 
U|ff@yahoo.co.in
D|jf@rediff.com
R|oop@hotmail.com
```